# Spock - Testing Exceptions with Data Tables

Tags: exception, testing, groovy, spock

How can exceptions be tested in a nice way (e.g. data tables) with Spock?

Example: Having a method `validateUser` that can throw exceptions with different messages or no exception if the user is valid.

The specification class itself:

```
class User { String userName }

class SomeSpec extends spock.lang.Specification {

    ...tests go here...

    private validateUser(User user) {
        if (!user) throw new Exception ('no user')
        if (!user.userName) throw new Exception ('no userName')
    }
}
```

**Variant 1**

This one is working but the real intention is cluttered by all the *when* / *then* labels and the repeated calls of `validateUser(user)`.

```
    def 'validate user - the long way - working but not nice'() {
        when:
        def user = new User(userName: 'tester')
        validateUser(user)

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()

        when:
        user = new User(userName: null)
        validateUser(user)

        then:
        def ex = thrown(Exception)
        ex.message == 'no userName'

        when:
        user = null
        validateUser(user)

        then:
        ex = thrown(Exception)
        ex.message == 'no user'
    }
```

**Variant 2**

This one is not working because of this error raised by Spock at compile time:

*Exception conditions are only allowed in 'then' blocks*

```
    def 'validate user - data table 1 - not working'() {
        when:
        validateUser(user)

        then:
        check()

        where:
        user                         || check
        new User(userName: 'tester') || { noExceptionThrown() }
        new User(userName: null)     || { Exception ex = thrown(); ex.message == 'no userName' }
        null                         || { Exception ex = thrown(); ex.message == 'no user' }
    }
```

**Variant 3**

This one is not working because of this error raised by Spock at compile time:

*Exception conditions are only allowed as top-level statements*

```
    def 'validate user - data table 2 - not working'() {
        when:
        validateUser(user)

        then:
        if (expectedException) {
            def ex = thrown(expectedException)
            ex.message == expectedMessage
        } else {
            noExceptionThrown()
        }

        where:
        user                         || expectedException | expectedMessage
        new User(userName: 'tester') || null              | null
        new User(userName: null)     || Exception         | 'no userName'
        null                         || Exception         | 'no user'
    }
```

Comment: Came across the same scenario last week and I did exactly what @peter has suggested. :) Handling two vairants of exception (thrown/notThrown) based on one data table is not the way. You cannot even have the thrown exception in the data table.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The recommended solution is to have two methods: one that tests the good cases, and another that tests the bad cases. Then both methods can make use of data tables.

Example:

```
class SomeSpec extends Specification {

    class User { String userName }

    def 'validate valid user'() {
        when:
        validateUser(user)

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()

        where:
        user << [
                new User(userName: 'tester'),
                new User(userName: 'joe')]
    }

    def 'validate invalid user'() {
        when:
        validateUser(user)

        then:
        def error = thrown(expectedException)
        error.message == expectedMessage

        where:
        user                     || expectedException | expectedMessage
        new User(userName: null) || Exception         | 'no userName'
        new User(userName: '')   || Exception         | 'no userName'
        null                     || Exception         | 'no user'
    }

    private validateUser(User user) {
        if (!user) throw new Exception('no user')
        if (!user.userName) throw new Exception('no userName')
    }

}
```

Comment: One question I remember, can't `thrown(MyException)` return null if `MyException` is not thrown?

Comment: I will have to revisit my test. But I was getting errors using thrown()/notThrown() in the data tables. Thanks anyways for a wonderful test framework. I became a "that-BDD-developer" in my work because of you. ;)

Comment: I could potentially work that way, but currently you can't pass `null` to `thrown()`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser This would be really useful with a basic example of how to handle exceptions within a data table. This is the top hit for "spock data exceptions" on Google and a reference example (or point to doc) would be very helpful Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the solution I came up with. It's basically Variant 3, but it uses a `try/catch` block to avoid using Spock's exception conditions (since those *have to be* top level).

```
def "validate user - data table 3 - working"() {
    expect:
    try {
        validateUser(user)
        assert !expectException
    }
    catch (UserException ex)
    {
        assert expectException
        assert ex.message == expectedMessage
    }

    where:
    user                         || expectException | expectedMessage
    new User(userName: 'tester') || false           | null
    new User(userName: null)     || true            | 'no userName'
    null                         || true            | 'no user'
}
```

**Some caveats:**

1. You need multiple catch blocks to test different exceptions.
2. You have to use explicit conditions (`assert` statements) inside of try/catch blocks.
3. You can't separate your stimulus and responses into `when-then` blocks.

Comment: Worked perfectly for my situation. I just updated to check exception only if message supplied: `assert !exceptionMessage`,  and can drop the `expectException` column.

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap your method call with a method that returns the message or the exception class, or a map of both...

```
  def 'validate user - data table 2 - not working'() {
        expect:
            expectedMessage == getExceptionMessage(&validateUser,user)
        where:
        user                         || expectedMessage
        new User(userName: 'tester') || null
        new User(userName: null)     || 'no userName'
        null                         || 'no user'
    }

    String getExceptionMessage(Closure c, Object... args){
        try{
            return c.call(args)
            //or return null here if you want to check only for exceptions
        }catch(Exception e){
            return e.message
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I do it, I modify the `when:` clause to always throw a `Success` exception, that way you don't need separate tests or logic to tell whether to call `thrown` or `notThrown`, just always call `thrown` with the data table telling whether to expect `Success` or not.

You could rename `Success` to be `None` or `NoException` or whatever you prefer.

```
class User { String userName }

class SomeSpec extends spock.lang.Specification {

    class Success extends Exception {}

    def 'validate user - data table 2 - working'() {
        when:
            validateUser(user)
            throw new Success ()

        then:
            def ex = thrown(expectedException)
            ex.message == expectedMessage

        where:
            user                         || expectedException | expectedMessage 
            new User(userName: 'tester') || Success           | null
            new User(userName: null)     || Exception         | 'no userName'
            null                         || Exception         | 'no user'
    }

    private validateUser(User user) {
        if (!user) throw new Exception ('no user')
        if (!user.userName) throw new Exception ('no userName')
    }
}
```

One extra thing I would change, would be to use a subclass for the failure exceptions too to avoid a `Success` being accidentally caught when you were really expecting a failure. It doesn't affect your example because you have an extra check for the message, but other tests might just test the exception type.

```
class Failure extends Exception {}
```

and use that or some other "real" exception instead of the vanilla `Exception`

Comment: IMO, throwing an exception indicating success is a pretty bad code smell. See Effective Java Item 69: Use Exceptions only for exceptional conditions.

Comment: It's only in the test that it's thrown, to work around a limitation of the framework, so IMO that type of heuristic doesn't apply, or is outweighed by the other smells that it masks.

Comment: clever! and reads well, to boot

Answer (score 5):

I have solution which not distort your test workflow and you can analyze exception by content of dynamic object placed in where table

```
@Unroll
def "test example [a=#a, b=#b]"() {
    given:
    def response
    def caughtEx

    when:
    try {
      result = someAmazingFunctionWhichThrowsSometimes(a,b)
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      caughtEx = ex
    }

    then:
    result == expected

    if (exception.expected) {
        assert caughtEx != null && exception.type.isInstance(caughtEx)
    } else {
        assert caughtEx == null
    }

    where:
    a    | b    || exception                                  | expected
    8    | 4    || [expected: false]                          | 2
    6    | 3    || [expected: false]                          | 3
    6    | 2    || [expected: false]                          | 3
    4    | 0    || [expected: true, type: RuntimeException]   | null

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the example from @AmanuelNega I had a try at this on the spock web console and saved the code at http://meetspock.appspot.com/script/5713144022302720

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class MathDemo {
    static determineAverage(...values) 
      throws IllegalArgumentException {
        for (item in values) {
            if (! (item instanceof Number)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException()
            }
        }

        if (!values) {
            return 0
        }

        return values.sum() / values.size()
    }
}

class AvgSpec extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    def "average of #values gives #result"(values, result){
        expect:
            MathDemo.determineAverage(*values) == result

        where:
            values       || result
            [1,2,3]      || 2
            [2, 7, 4, 4] || 4.25
            []           || 0
    }

    @Unroll
    def "determineAverage called with #values throws #exception"(values, exception){
        setup:
           def e = getException(MathDemo.&determineAverage, *values)

        expect:
            exception == e?.class

        where:
            values       || exception
            ['kitten', 1]|| java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            [99, true]   || java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            [1,2,3]      || null
    }

    Exception getException(closure, ...args){
        try{
            closure.call(args)
            return null
        } catch(any) {
            return any
        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I achieved it using `@Unroll` and the `when:`, `then:`, and `where:` blocks. It runs using all 3 of the tests with the data from the data table:

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import java.util.regex.Pattern

class MyVowelString {
    private static final Pattern HAS_VOWELS = Pattern.compile('[aeiouAEIOU]')
    final String string

    MyVowelString(String string) {
        assert string != null && HAS_VOWELS.matcher(string).find()
        this.string = string
    }
}

class PositiveNumberTest extends Specification {
    @Unroll
    def "invalid constructors with argument #number"() {
        when:
        new MyVowelString(string)

        then:
        thrown(AssertionError)

        where:
        string | _
        ''     | _
        null   | _
        'pppp' | _
    }
}
```